# How to bring information bar in the development for IE Browser Toolbar

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, browser, toolbar

I am new to toolbar development. I have developed a toolbar using the c# bandobject and its working fine.

I want to show the information bar if the users enter the username and password to login in the webbrowser in the same way the browser will show "save password" "Never for this site" with my customize message.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

IE's information bar is not extensible; it's a security feature of IE.

If you need to display a message to the user, you will need to create your own UI.